# How do I optimize this simple matlab code?

Tags: matlab

Sorry for the vague title and that this is probably an asked question before, unfortunatly I had no idea how to explain what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to turn this matlab code

```
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
x = zeros(1000);
y = zeros(1000);
u = 1;
for i = linspace(0,2*pi,1000)
    x(u) = (1 + cos(i))*cos(i);
    y(u) = (1 + cos(i))*sin(i);
    u = u + 1;
end
plot(x,y)
```

into something like this:

```
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
x = (1 + cos(theta))*cos(theta);
y = (1 + cos(theta))*sin(theta);
end
plot(x,y)
```

but since I'm using the matrix theta twice it doesn't understand how to do it. I've seen code written like this before but I don't recall what I'm doing wrong, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try using element by element multiplication by using `.*`, not matrix multiplication, which is  just `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David is correct; the .* strikes again. This code will work:

```
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
x = (1 + cos(theta)).*cos(theta);
y = (1 + cos(theta)).*sin(theta);
plot(x,y)
```